# Application.VLookup function always returns #N/A

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use the Application.VLookup function in Visual Basic to find a value in a different workbook. However, whenever I use it, it always returns #N/A.

This is the layout of my function. LastRow() just returns the row number of the last row. SHORTAGE_SBT is a variable containing the source workbook name. SBT_Last is the last row of SHORTAGE_SBT. The ID that I'm searching with in in the B column, hence why I use "B" & ind to refer to it.

```
For ind = 4 To LastRow()
    Range("H" & ind).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Application.VLookup("B" & ind, Workbooks(SHORTAGE_SBT).Sheets(1).Range("A14:DZ" & SBT_Last), Range("DZ1").Column, False)
Next
```

I have tried recording a macro for VLookup to see if it would help me understand the problem. The macro gave me this function, which worked but could not be used because it contains the hardcoded file name instead of using the variable.

```
Range("H" & ind).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'[filename.xls]Sheet1'!R14C1:R2382C130, COLUMN(R[-3]C[122]), FALSE)"
```

I cannot see any significant difference between the way the macro lays out the arguments of the function as opposed to mine, other than using more direct references. I have tried using direct numbers in my code but doing so hasn't helped either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Application.VLookup("B" & ind, Workbooks(SHORTAGE_SBT).Sheets(1).Range("A14:DZ" & SBT_Last), Range("DZ1").Column, False)
> ```

`"B" & ind` will be searched for "literally"; it will not be transformed into a range address because it is interpreted here by *VBA*, not by *Excel*. Try:

```
Application.VLookup(Range("B" & ind), Workbooks(SHORTAGE_SBT).Sheets(1).Range("A14:DZ" & SBT_Last),  Range("DZ1").Column, False)
'                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: It's always the little things that screw you over. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

Combine the two approaches:

```
Range("H" & ind).FormulaR1C1 = _
            & "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'[" & Workbooks(SHORTAGE_SBT)  _
            & "]Sheet1'!R14C1:R2382C130, COLUMN(R[-3]C[122]), FALSE)"
```

Comment: Didn't know multi-line statements were possible in VBA. Thanks.

Comment: I'm a new user, so my upvotes aren't visible yet. :/